# AudioManager.setStreamVolume without showing sliders

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

What flag should be set so that there is no soundEffect/vibration/show_ui when volume is adjusted?

```
audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 10, flag);
```

Is it `FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE` or

```
~FLAG_SHOW_UI|~FLAG_VIBRATE|~FLAG_PLAY_SOUND
```

Answer (score 2):

you just need set flag to 0 and should work

```
audioManager.setStreamVolume(
            AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            desiredLevel,
            0 // this should be 0 instead AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI
        )
```

Comment: Thank you, it works for me on Android 10!

Answer (score 0):

To remove the vibration and UI on mute, use:

```
audio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

It isn't possible to remove the sound/UI when setting the streamvolume back to normal.